# Algorithm/Model for assigning rounds of passengers in shared cars with scattered timetables

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics, resource-scheduling

I am trying to model the following problem: a set of people (teacher of school in the reality) must reach the office each one at different hours (i.e. people 1 enters at hour 2 and exits at hour 7, people 2 enters at hour 4 exits at hour 6 and so on). These times changes depending on the day of the week following a given timetable. 
In order to reach the office people with same starting hour meet in a common place and share a car. Similarly when they have to come back from office they will sort in the cars of drivers leaving at given hour to reach the common place near their houses. The problem is how to assign a driver and a crew for each turn so that:

1. all people can find place in a turn (both in departure and return)
2. in each turn there is a maximum number of persons (due to the limited car places)
3. minimize the total number of cars used
4. each person should drive the car the same number of the other (or make as even as possible the use of each car/driver)

The input therefore is a table like:
**Mon**: Andrew 1-3 (hour of departure-return), Bill 2-5, Cindy 1-7 ...
**Tue**: Andrew 2-7, Bill 1-6, Cindy 2-4 ...
**Wed**: ...

while the output should be
**Mon**: *Departures*: hour 1 (driver Andrew, crew: Cindy, Steve), hour 2 (driver Bill, crew: Steve, Frank)... *Returns*: hour 3 (driver Andrew, crew: Jim, Lisa), hour 4 (driver Mary, crew: David, Pete)...
**Tue**: *Departures* hour 1 (driver Bill, crew: Richard, Dan, Pete), hour 2 (driver Andrew, crew: Cindy, Bob) ...
**Wed**...

Comment: I'm a big fan of using constraint solvers like [Z3](https://z3.codeplex.com/) on problems like this.